# Issue with plugin sub menu and pages

Tags: plugin-development, menus

For some reason my plugin sub page that I have made isn't showing up or working. The plugin activates and shows the top level menu, but not the sub menu. Anyone help? Code below:

```
<?php

function new_menu(){
    add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
    }
    add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'new_menu');
function test_sub_menu(){
$parent_slug = 'new-menu';
$page_title = 'Sub menu';
$menu_title = 'Sub menu';
$capability = 'edit_pages';
$menu_slug  = 'new-menu';

}
function new_menu_page(){
    ?>
  <h1>Content goes here.</h1>

<?php
}
function test_sub_menu_page(){
    ?>
  <h1>Sub menu page content goes here.</h1>

    <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a syntax error, extra close-curly in `new_menu()`. Your `test_sub_menu()` function has all the vars that are used in `new_menu()` -  but they're not global or called to from `new_menu()`, so they do nothing and the functions do nothing but return undefined errors.

`$parent_slug = 'new-menu';` should be instead, for a subpage, the page you want it under. To go under "Pages" you'll want the slug to be `edit.php?post_type=page`.

The following will do what you're after:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    $parent_slug = 'edit.php?post_type=page'; // "Pages"
    $page_title = 'My Plugin Submenu Page';
    $menu_title = 'My Plugin Submenu Page';
    $capability = 'edit_pages';
    $menu_slug  = 'myplugin-submenu-page';
    $page = 'myplugin_submenu_page';

    add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $page);
});
function myplugin_submenu_page(){
    echo "<h1>Sub menu page content goes here.</h1>";
}
```

All documentation and examples is here in [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)

If you want to find what the `$parent_slug` is, at the start of the above action function you can see Wordpress's admin menu and submenu with something like:

```
global $menu, $submenu;

echo "<pre>MENU: \n".print_r(￼$menu,true)."</pre>";
echo "<pre>SUB-MENU: \n".print_r(￼$submenu,true)."</pre>";
die;
```

There you'll find all the info on the current navigations so you can tap into it.